# What is the scope of the controllers in .net project?

Tags: .net-6.0

I have created a new web api project and along with it there is the WeatherForecast controller with a GET method.

I want to ask - what is the scope of the controller class?

Since I don't find any Dependency injection setup for controller, is it by default singleton or scoped?

Comment: Why are you asking? A new controller instances is created to serve each request. In that sense a controller is scoped because it (or rather the request it serves) actually defines the scope

Comment: Controllers should follow the Explicit Dependencies Principle. You can read about it here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scope of a controller in all ASP.NET stacks since ASP.NET MVC 1.0 is the request - a new Controller instance is created by the ASP.NET middleware to handle each request.

The ASP.NET Core middleware pipeline is [pretty deep though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order), and controller instances are only created in the last stage, in the `Endpoint` middleware.

[image]

They controller and the action that handles the request are the `User Code` box in the endpoint pipelines

[image]

You'll have to assume that the controller will be disposed very soon after an action method finishes processing a request. It won't be safe to access a controller instance from any other class after that point, even other scoped classes.

If you want to share data you'll have to store it in some other place, eg the Session, a cache, use common Options objects, a singleton Dictionary (essentially a cache), a database etc.